# Error Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets' when upgraded to React Native version 0.71

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am having some problems when my project is upgraded to React Native version 0.71, I have tried many ways to solve it but it is not working, hope everyone can help.
I am getting below error.

[image]